# How to disable a commandbutton in primefaces and need to enable on some text input

Tags: primefaces

I need some help on primefaces, i have a command-button which needs to be disabled initially
and when i input some text in the inputtext field the button should get enable.

Can someone please provide me a sample code.

Comment: show how you disabling the `submit` button?If you know how to do it, then you should know how to enable it

Comment: I just gave as disabled ="true"

Comment: <p:commandButton value="Submit" update="msgs"
    actionListener="#{dropSelect.displayLocation}" disabled="#{dropSelect.disable}" style="float:right;"/>


public boolean isDisable() {
  return disable;
 }

public void setDisable(boolean disable) {
  this.disable = disable;
 }

Answer (score 0):

You can set the enable and disable value to boolean ...and have an ajax event to update it .

Have you tried implementing it through javascript ??
Enabling or disabling a button is preferably done on the client side using javascript rather than to make a call to the managed bean.